# How to count join on other table

Tags: mysql

How to count base on the others table `sum`

I have this tables

`CARDS`

```
|   ID  |   Name    |
---------------------
|   1   |   Nice    |
|   2   |   Wow     |
|   3   |   Lol     |
|   4   |   Ohyeah  |
|   5   |   Olala   |
```

`VOTES`

```
ID  |   *card_id*   |   *user_id*   |   vote    |
-------------------------------------------------
1   |       1       |       1       |   -1      |
2   |       2       |       2       |   -1      |
3   |       2       |       4       |   1       |
4   |       2       |       5       |   1       |
5   |       3       |       2       |   1       |
6   |       3       |       1       |   1       |
```

RESULT QUERY WHAT I WANT

```
|   card_id     |   total_votes |
-------------------------------
|   1           |   -1      |
|   2           |   1       |
|   3           |   2       |
|   4           |   0       |
|   5           |   0       |
```

and this is what I've tried

```
SELECT c.*, COALESCE(SUM(v.vote),0) as vote_count 
FROM cards c 
LEFT JOIN votes v ON c.id = v.card_id
```

I don't where I mistake, please need help

Comment: fixed... sorry didn't notice

Comment: @Strawberry stop editting wrong please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need subquery, just the group by

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cac3/5)**

```
SELECT c.`ID`, 
       COALESCE(Sum(v.vote), 0) AS total_votes 
FROM   cards c 
       LEFT JOIN votes v 
              ON c.id = v.`card_id`
GROUP  BY c.`ID`;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | total_votes |
|----|-------------|
|  1 |          -1 |
|  2 |           1 |
|  3 |           2 |
|  4 |           0 |
|  5 |           0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select all votes and group them by card_id. There u can simply use SUM function.

```
SELECT c.id, COALESCE(SUM(v.vote), 0) 
FROM VOTES 
LEFT JOIN c ON v.card_id = c.ID 
GROUP BY v.card_id
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza fixed

Answer (score 0):

Following query will do the trick

```
select c.id, sum(v.vote)
from cards c, votes v
where c.id = v.card_id
group by c.id
```